# Swiper - wrong width on init, correct width after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I am working on a project using Swiper and everythings working fine after resizing the window. But on init the width of the slides is not correct. I tried reproducing this locally but without success. I set 4 slides per View, but it's calculating the width for 3 1/2 slides. I cleared everything except slidesPerView from my configuration but no change at all. Could it be some kind of collision with other frameworks or plugins? If additional information is needed to solve this issue, just ask! :-)

**EDIT**

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery_container">
    <div id="galleryLeft"></div>
    <div id="gallery-swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="galleryRight"></div>
</div>
```

Initialisation:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var gallery_swiper = new Swiper('#gallery-swiper', {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            speed: 500,
            prevButton: '#galleryLeft',
            nextButton: '#galleryRight'
        });

        var slides = gallery_swiper.slides.length;
        if(slides < 4) {
            $('#galleryLeft').css("display", "none");
            $('#galleryRight').css("display", "none");
            $('#gallery_container').css({
                "padding": "0"
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Maybe notable is that the gallery_container is responsive. The slider is placed inside a column.

Comment: you need to provide some code here

Comment: @edisoni.1337 do you have any ideas?

Comment: build a js fiddle please because i can't get it work with this plugin or framework whatever it is

Comment: @edisoni.1337 I tried hard to reproduce this issue, but it's not not working. After I removed the JS of the mmenu plugin it worked. I tried this in a local file and it's working fine with mmenu. Can't figure out where the problem hides. Any idea how to check this out?

Comment: I've found the issue. It was about the ranking of the initialisation scripts. The swiper was in the middle of the html-syntax initiated while the mmenu was initiated at the bottom of the body, which is pushing the wrapper to the right after the slider was already build up. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I have the same problem, can you make a clear answer and resolve solution?

Answer (score 8):

Simple and nice solution that worked for me, after some wasted hours:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
// init swiper here
}, false);
```

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all
>   dependent resources such as stylesheets and images.

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

---

If this doesn't work for you, make sure you check out the thread where I found this fix:
src: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2218#issuecomment-509683102

There are other possible solutions (eg: Browser extensions could also cause this problem):

Cheers, I hope this helps somebody!